# What is the difference between specialization and specialisation?

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between specialization  and specialisation ? where am i use

specialization   and specialisation  what does meaning of both.?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning (specializing in a certain skill). However, different English-speaking countries have different spelling preferences. "Specialisation" and "specialise" would be used in a British context, whereas Canadians and Americans would use "specialization" and "specialize." This is true of many words ending in -ization or -ize: realize/realise (realization/realisation), organize/organise (organise/organisation), idolize/idolise, etc.